# Dynamically rendering user controls using Server.Execute performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, user-controls

We have a scenario where we need to render a user control but not within the calling page. This causes a performance issue as I believe that when a user control is first rendered in a page it is somehow compiled, optimised and cached.

Please I dont need any advice that this is the wrong way to do it and it should be rendered in the page - I know this is preferable but is not possible.

So the code looks like this:

```
System.Web.UI.Page pageHolder = new System.Web.UI.Page();
UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(inPath);

pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
return output.ToString();
```

It performs very poorly compared to when the usercontrol is embedded into a page. I was wondering whether there was something similar to Razor where its possible to call Razor.Parse() and pass in the third parameter as the cache name. Or some other route I have not managed to discover.

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried calling `pageHolder.FrameworkInitialize(); viewControl.Render(/* htmlWriter here */)`?

Comment: What version of .net is that available in?

Comment: All of them, kind-of. `FrameworkInitialize` is meant for the .net framework and may now show up in your intellisense. There may also be more setup required to allow you to call `Render` without passing through the complete request chain.